# Why does MockMvc always return empty content()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to test my rest api with mockMvc.

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/users/1/mobile")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(content().string("iPhone"))
```

The test failed because of:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response content 
Expected :iPhone
Actual   :
```

From the output of `print()`, I can know the API actually returned the expected string "iPhone".

```
ModelAndView:
        View name = users/1/mobile
             View = null
        Attribute = treeNode
            value = "iPhone"
           errors = []
```

And I guess the empty "Actual" above is caused by empty "Body" below

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = users/1/mobile
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

My questions are:

1. Why `MockHttpServletResponse's` Body is empty;
2. How can I correctly test the response of API.

Comment: Please add the controller you're testing (the *Subject Under Test*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your action methods (methods with `@RequestMapping` annotation) return instances of `ModelAndView` or you work with `Model`, you have to test it using [`MockMvcResultMatchers#model`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#model--) function:

```
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("phone", "iPhone"))
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().size(1))
```

[`MockMvcResultMatchers#content`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#content--) is appropriate for REST action methods (methods with `@RequestBody` annotation).

---

To have a better understanding about testing Spring MVC and Spring REST controllers check these links:

- [Testing of Spring MVC Applications: Forms](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-forms/)
- [Testing of Spring MVC Applications: REST API](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-rest-api-part-one/)

Comment: but those are just the attributes of the model, is there any way to test the view render?

Answer (score 6):

Just adding another reason for this error, that took me a whole day to discover. I successfully created an APITest using mockito and mockmvc class, using the perform method. Then copied the code to produce another service and I started to get an empty body over and over again.

Nonetheless, at the end of the day I decided to compare each copied class from one project to another. The only one difference that I found was the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation in my request DTO that is received by the new controller.

So, the recommendation is: add the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation in your DTO classes.

Comment: That is the true answer. Great...

Comment: Amazing. This really did the trick for me! Thank you.